# How to add authentication in Click-once Application Deployment

Tags: authentication, clickonce, setup-project, setup-deployment

I tried to deploy the WPF application in click once deployment.It will check the network location for updates.Is there any possibility to make the network location as trusted location or how can I add a authentication for this.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows authorization is definitely the easiest way to achieve access control to the manifests and application files.

The most straightforward way is to simply set Access Control List (ACL) permissions to restrict access to the ClickOnce application files to only authorized users or groups.

For more authentication mechanisms please see the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa480721(v=msdn.10)#limiting-access-to-clickonce-applications).